# Adding current quarter to email subject - Python

Tags: python, email, win32com

I am trying to write a script that will add the current quarter to the subject of an email but I'm not sure if it is possible, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see code below:

```
import win32com.client as client
import datetime

# Get Quarter
Today=datetime.datetime.now()

# Using Pandas Timestamp to get quarter
TodayTimeStamp=pd.Timestamp(Today)
quarter = TodayTimeStamp.quarter
quarter



# Send the email
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

# Mail item
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
message.To = "Louise.Sweeney.Contractor@pepsico.com"
message.Subject = "File Q"+quarter    
message.HTMLBody = "Hello World"
message.Send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're facing any errors, but there should be no problem with adding this to your subject you just make sure to transform the quarter to string type. you can do that like the following

```
message.Subject = f'File Q{quarter}'
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I was missing the brackets. Can I ask what the f at the start does?

Comment: @PythonBeginner the f is a new kind of string formatting in python it's introduced in python 3.6, it's like saying `"File Q{}".format(quarter)` if you are aware of this. You can check more about different kinds of formatting in python here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/